# Run release build version using cordova iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I want to test the ***release build version*** on my iOS device directly using this command:

```
cordova run --buildConfig=build.json ios --release --device
```

But not working, is anybody here manage to test the release build version running on device? Thanks in advance.

Or let say the worst case, we can't do it. Is there any guarantee that below command:

```
cordova build --buildConfig=build.json ios --release
```

will build the release version of our app, when we open the xcode project on xcode?

My point is I need to get the release version build by cordova, not by Xcode.

Comment: "But not working" any compiler error msg? Did you stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

Likely not guaranteed, but that's just a guess.

I'm not sure why you need Cordova to put together a release build—in order to submit to the app store you will want to use Xcode to archive your app. I have no idea if Cordova can do a proper archive but personally I wouldn't rely on it because at least Xcode should be up to date on what Apple demands from the build. Especially with automatic code signing. Cordova may lag in its implementation when Apple changes things.

One little thing, when a .ipa is signed for distribution through the app store, you cannot side load it onto a device. You can only side load .ipas that are signed for development.